# Django+Mongodb file upload returns default primary key error

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to write a simple file upload application with django + mongodb. I have set my SITE_ID properly (I am writing to the db).

Using the admin page, I can upload a file (and the file appears in the dir structure), but when I click on the filename:

[image: filepath]

It gives me this error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/myapp/fileUpload/534855062da57ae6ecc4399f/myapp/files/1_2.jpg/
AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'534855062d...' instead).
```

This is the code I'm using:

**models.py**

```
class fileUpload(models.Model):
    some_file_location = models.FileField(upload_to='myapp/files/')
```

**admin.py**

```
admin.site.register(fileUpload)
```

**DB Entry:**

> db.myapp_fileupload.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("53484e4e2da57ad214df5072"), "some_file_location" : "myapp/files/1.jpg" }

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the incompatibility of mongo and django. I have run into many problems with this, and at this point, a new solution (db or framework) is the best way to go.